# How would I be able to query depending on array length?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a project where a user selects a group and then can choose what role they are looking for in that group.

It looks something like this:

```
let group = await models.Group.findById(user.groupID);
let seekGroupRole = await models.GroupRole.findById(user.seekingGroupRole);

let test = await models.Profile.aggregate([
          {
            $match: {
              $or: [
                { _id: { $in: group.members } },
                { _id: { $in: seekGroupRole.profiles } },
              ],
            },
          },
          { $group: { _id: "$_id" } },
]);
console.log(test);
```

Now we are adding a way to select multiple roles. How would I go about doing this without having to do multiple queries?

Is something like this possible?

```
let group = await models.Group.findById(user.groupID);
let seekGroupRole = await models.GroupRole.find({
    _id: { $in: user.seekingGroupRole}
});

let test = await models.Profile.aggregate([
          {
            $match: {
              $or: [
                { _id: { $in: group.members } },
                { _id: { $in: seekGroupRole.profiles } },
              ],
            },
          },
          { $group: { _id: "$_id" } },
]);
console.log(test);
```

Now `seekGroupRole` is an array. It could have the length of 1 or more. So it would be `seekGroupRole[0].profiles, seekGroupRole[1].profiles,` etc...

What is the best way to accomplish this? Should I for loop and merge the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is using for loop with concat to avoid multiple queries.

```
let seekGroupRole = await models.GroupRole.find({
    _id: { $in: user.seekingGroupRole}
});
let allRoles;
for (let i = 0; i < seekGroupRole.length; i++) {
   if (i == 0) {
     allRoles = seekGroupRole[i].profiles;
   }
   if (i > 0) {
     allRoles = allRoles.concat(
       seekGroupRole[i].profiles
        );
   }
}

let test = await models.Profile.aggregate([
          {
            $match: {
              $or: [
                { _id: { $in: group.members } },
                { _id: { $in: allRoles } },
              ],
            },
          },
          { $group: { _id: "$_id" } },
]);
```